# How to configure the flex crossdomain.xml in Python Google App Engine Sdk

Tags: python, flash, apache-flex, google-app-engine, crossdomain.xml

I have created a flex application in the Python Gae sdk and I got the error 2048, so I put a crossdomain.xml under the static folder.
The crossdomain.xml is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM “/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd”>
<cross-domain-policy> 
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/> 
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/> 
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

And, I add the following in the app.yaml:

```
- url: /crossdomain.xml 
  static_files: static/crossdomain.xml 
  upload: static/crossdomain.xml
```

However, I still got the error 2048.  Therefore, I would like to know is anything I need to configure or miss in my case and how to fix the error.

Please advice.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about Google App Engine, nor it's directory structure; but the crossdomain.xml file must be in the web root of the server whose remote services you are accessing. It is not clear to m where you had put it in relation to your app and the services you're calling. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  For Gae, we can not direct access its file system, we need to set the services or file in the app.yaml.

Comment: It's not the filesystem that's important, it's the `domain.com/crossdomain.xml` location that's going to matter to the FlashPlayer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used crossdomain.xml with Flash, but I have with Unity3d. I've gotten it to work, and what you have looks correct.

Have you visited yoursite.com/crossdomain.xml to make sure it's visible in a browser?

If Flash is really picky you might need to specify a mimetype (text/xml or application/xml)

```
- url: /crossdomain.xml 
  mime_type: text/xml
  static_files: static/crossdomain.xml 
  upload: static/crossdomain.xml
```

You also might want to check you crossdomain.xml in a validator to make sure you're not missing a /> or something like that.

Also, check out [html5boilerplate's crossdomain.xml](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/crossdomain.xml).  Their least restrictive version should work on any site:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>


<!-- Read this: www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html -->

<!-- Most restrictive policy: -->
<!--
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="none"/>
-->


<!-- Least restrictive policy: -->
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
<!--
  If you host a crossdomain.xml file with allow-access-from domain=“*”      
  and don’t understand all of the points described here, you probably       
  have a nasty security vulnerability. ~ simon willison
-->

</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Thanks Calvin, I appreciate your help.  I can view the crossdomain.xml by "http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml".  I have tried adding the "mime_type: text/xml", actually I have tried it before I post the question, and use your crossdomain.xml, but I still got error 2048.

Comment: Are you pulling data from a source besides localhost? Because I think that domain would need to allow crossdomain access. At one point I also had `<allow-access-from domain="localhost" to-ports="*" />` in it, but was more restrictive.

Comment: The other domain already have a crossdomain.xml, I also can access it.

Comment: I'm pretty stumped. Maybe you could do a [packet trace](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3994) to see which crossdomain.xml files your app is requesting (or is that what fiddler does)?

Comment: Yes, fiddler will do the packet trace.  But I do not see the local crossdomain.xml is requested during the load of operation.

Comment: Have a look at this michael, it may help... http://goo.gl/usvHZ - `loadPolicyFile` allows you to load a crossdomain.xml from an arbitrary location on the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

FlashPlayer is looking for the `crossdomain.xml` file in the URL domain root, e.g.

```
domain.com/crossdomain.xml
```

Is where the FlashPlayer wants to find it.

However, you can use `Security.loadPolicyFile(url)` to load a `crossdomain.xml` file from an alternate location on the server.

[More info on Adobe livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#loadPolicyFile%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Gae is quit difficult to define the domain root.  Please refer to the update.

Comment: I have already tried Security.loadPolicyFile(url).  The crossdomain.xml can be loaded, but I still get the error.