# How to configure the flex crossdomain.xml in tipfy

Tags: apache-flex, google-app-engine, crossdomain.xml, tipfy

I would like to know how to configure the flex crossdomain.xml in tipfy with the Google app engine skd.

Please advice.  Thanks.

Edit:

Tipfy is a framework using in Gae.

I would like to know:

1. where I can place the crossdomain.xml, in the root or other place,
2. do I need script to redirect to the xml,
3. what files that I need to modify, eg. app.yaml.
4. any other things or file I need to modify or create to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you need in particular?

Comment: I don't know what tipfy is; can you explain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure the flex crossdomain.xml in Python Google App Engine Sdk.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993157/how-to-configure-the-flex-crossdomain-xml-in-python-google-app-engine-sdk)

Comment: I feel sorry If I waste anyone's time.  The first question is using the webapp with the Gae.  All the settings seen to be Ok, but it do now work.  I have tried to solve it for several days, but I cannot fix it.  That's why I tried to use the framework to solve.  I am not sure url.py in tifpy can solve the problems, so I post this question.  Nick, please give some hints for the above question.  Thanks.

Comment: @michael Serving it with app.yaml is still your best option. It _is_ practical, you just need to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the crossdomain.xml anywhere in your app (eg, the root of the app), then use a [static file handler](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers) to configure it in app.yaml. You don't need to touch any framework code at all.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for answer.  Actually, I do not use any framwork for the moment, but it do not work.  Please refer to my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993157/how-to-configure-the-flex-crossdomain-xml-in-python-google-app-engine-sdk.

Comment: @michael Please don't post duplicate questions - you waste my time, your time, and that of anyone else who reads the duplicate.

Comment: I have tried and it do not work for me using the static file handler in both tipfy and webapp.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GAE the app url will be typically http://myapp.appspot.com and the Flash player will need a cross domain file from http://myapp.appspot.com/crossdomain.xml. In a Java environment it is as simple as creating this file in web folder of the project, that's it. It will be the same for Python, put this in your app's web root folder, not Google's web server root folder. This worked for me.